Multiple plots from different dataframes into the same plot
I have three dataframes, T_N_6190, T_N_9120, and T_N_2123.
T_N_6190:
structure(list(Hydrojahr = c(1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966,
    1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 
    1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
    1989, 1990), T_m = c(9.75963470319635, 8.18401826484018, 7.7496803652968, 
    8.69225865209472, 8.31525114155251, 8.71534246575342, 9.7797514619883, 
    9.14398907103825, 8.04849315068493, 7.43212328767123, 8.92219178082192, 
    8.7323087431694, 8.82506849315068, 8.85869863013699, 9.93952054794521, 
    8.61632513661202, 8.57938356164384, 8.77034246575342, 7.97739726027397, 
    7.94153005464481, 8.97431506849315, 8.87732876712329, 10.1515753424658, 
    8.39637978142077, 8.23602739726027, 8.06349315068493, 7.46054794520548, 
    9.38825136612022, 9.97842465753425, 9.99150684931507), N_s = c(874.4, 
    619.1, 435.1, 506.2, 597.5, 711.6, 705.8, 577.8, 651.8, 583.1, 
    545.8, 553.3, 420.1, 562.7, 624.7, 385.7, 619.5, 603.3, 584.7, 
    661.6, 694.5, 506, 586.6, 564.7, 513.4, 644.8, 714.2, 568.5, 
    415.6, 673.4)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -30L))

T_N_9120:
structure(list(Hydrojahr = c(1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020), T_m = c(8.95930918281382, 10.3787795992714, 8.99625570776256, 
9.60173515981735, 10.0106849315068, 7.54653916211293, 9.4441095890411, 
9.93287671232877, 10.0211872146119, 10.2435336976321, 10.1421917808219, 
10.8183561643836, 9.99534246575342, 9.76693989071038, 9.99506849315068, 
10.0458447488584, 11.9687671232877, 10.6469034608379, 10.3304109589041, 
9.38356164383562, 9.81753424657534, 10.4704007285975, 9.48785388127854, 
11.4050228310502, 11.1631050228311, 11.5071038251366, 10.1428310502283, 
11.8284931506849, 11.8727853881279, 11.7700364298725), N_s = c(530.9, 
515.4, 662.4, 784.5, 624.3, 418.7, 462.8, 534.6, 501, 552.6, 
562.3, 735.4, 469.6, 619.3, 635, 534.1, 790, 503.9, 525.7, 685.9, 
673.8, 588, 632.4, 610.6, 515, 516.5, 722.5, 451.9, 485.5, 514.6
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))   

T_N_2123:
structure(list(Hydrojahr = c(2021, 2022, 2023), T_m = c(10.6240182648402, 
11.513698630137, 12.0459437751004), N_s = c(586.7, 437.7, 585.2
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

I want to plot three dataframes on same plot in r, here is my code:
p <- ggplot()+
geom_point(aes(x = T_m, y = N_s), T_N_6190, color = "gray") +
geom_point(aes(x = T_m, y = N_s), T_N_9120, color = "gray35") +
geom_point(aes(x = T_m, y = N_s), T_N_2123 %>% filter(Hydrojahr == 2021), color = "firebrick4", size = 10.6)+
geom_point(aes(x = T_m, y = N_s), T_N_2123 %>% filter(Hydrojahr == 2022), color = "firebrick1", size = 11.5)+
geom_point(aes(x = T_m, y = N_s), T_N_2123 %>% filter(Hydrojahr == 2023), color = "darkorange", size = 12)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(T_N_6190$T_m)), linewidth = 0.5, color = "gray", linetype ="dashed")+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(T_N_6190$N_s)), linewidth = 0.5, color = "gray", linetype ="dashed")+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(T_N_9120$T_m)), linewidth = 0.5, color = "gray35", linetype ="dashed")+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(T_N_9120$N_s)), linewidth = 0.5, color = "gray35", linetype ="dashed")+
geom_text(data = T_N_2123, aes(x = T_m, y = N_s, label = Hydrojahr),hjust =-0.5, vjust =-0.5)+
labs(title = "Thermopluviogramm der Stadt xxx", subtitle = "Hydrologisches Jahr",
x = "Mittlere Temperatur [°C]", y = "Niederschlagssumme [mm]",
caption = "Daten: xxx, Erstellt: xxx") +
theme_linedraw()

And the plot turns out below:

but somehow there is no legend, and the size of the point for year 2021, 2022, 2023 only works when I put a number, not size = T_m or size = T_N_2123$Tm.
and if I add the color inside aes(), the color of point will not be the one which I defined, the plot shows like: 

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. ggplot will only generate a legend for properties mapped in an aes(). It would probably be better if you reshaped your data into one data.frame with some sort of indicator value prior to plotting. That will simplify the code and make creating the legend much easier.

Please share a few rows of sample data from your data frames. (Sharing 5 rows each from 2 data frames is probably plenty to illustrate the issue). dput() is the nicest way to share data as it makes copy/pasteable R code to recreate the data, e.g., dput(T_N_2123[1:5, ]) for the first 5 rows.

Adding to what the other user said, your plot has no legend because you didn't specify any variable for color, fill or size inside the aes function.

I see you've added a bunch of rows from 1 data frame. Since this problem is about multiple data frames, we'll probably need data from 2 of them. But we probably don't need many rows, 5 row might be plenty, maybe 10 if really needed. And it's very nice if you can use dput() as in my comment above, as that will give us copy/pasteable R code to make the data, and will include details like the data structure and column classes so there is no ambiguity.

@GregorThomas, Hi, thanks for your comments and hints. I've already added another dataframe T_N_2123 using dput(), I'm not quite sure whether I used it correctly. Please put it right if it is wrong.

That's not what dput results should look like. It should be something like structure(list(Hydrojahr = c(.... It's R code to create the data. Don't run dput on your whole data, just a few rows dput(T_N_2123[1:5, ])

Thanks for adding the dput for one of the data frames. The one that starts with structure(list(... is perfect. Could you edit the others to use dput() as well?

Hi, there, the another two dataframes are now added. Please check.

In this approach I first bind the data from two data frames into one, and calculate the means prior to plotting.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

df <- bind_rows(T_N_6190 = T_N_6190,
                T_N_9120 = T_N_9120,
                .id = 'source')

means <- df |>
  summarise(T_m = mean(T_m),
            N_s = mean(N_s),
            .by = source)

glimpse(means)
#> Rows: 2
#> Columns: 3
#> $ source <chr> "T_N_6190", "T_N_9120"
#> $ T_m    <dbl> 8.750039, 10.256452
#> $ N_s    <dbl> 590.1833, 578.6400

I chose to keep the T_N_2123 data frame as a separate object and add a separate color scale with the help of ggnewscale::new_scale_color().
df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = T_m, y = N_s)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = source)) +
  geom_vline(data = means, aes(xintercept = T_m, color = source),
             linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_hline(data = means, aes(yintercept = N_s, color = source),
             linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 'dashed') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray', 'gray35')) +
  labs(color = '') +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data = T_N_2123, aes(color = factor(Hydrojahr), size = factor(Hydrojahr))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('firebrick4', 'firebrick1', 'darkorange')) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(10.6, 11.5, 12)) +
  geom_text(data = T_N_2123, aes(label = Hydrojahr), hjust =-0.5, vjust =-0.5) +
  theme_linedraw() +
  labs(title = "Thermopluviogramm der Stadt xxx", subtitle = "Hydrologisches Jahr",
       x = "Mittlere Temperatur [°C]", y = "Niederschlagssumme [mm]",
       caption = "Daten: xxx, Erstellt: xxx", 
       color = 'Jahr', size = 'Jahr')


Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0
